# Using awk to search backwards by line, and append result to next the line

Tags: awk, hosts-file, dnsmasq

I am trying to generate a temporary hosts file, which is based on a DNS log provided by dnsmasq. I have got it mostly working, however I am having a problem with CNAMEs. I will show what I have achieved so far.

There are 3 types of responses in the log which I need to obtain. The simplest is very easy to extract from the log, eg

```
Jun 20 14:27:59 dnsmasq[2551]: reply stackoverflow.com is 64.34.119.12
```

This can be output to "64.34.119.12 stackoverflow.com" using

```
grep reply /tmp/dnslog | grep -v 'NXDOMAIN\|NODATA' | awk '{print $8 " " $6}'
```

The other type of log concerns CNAMEs, here is one example;

```
Jun 20 14:42:11 dnsmasq[2551]: reply www.videolan.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 14:42:11 dnsmasq[2551]: reply ganesh.videolan.org is 88.191.250.2
```

This can be output to "88.191.250.2 ganesh.videolan.org www.videolan.org" using

```
grep reply /tmp/dnslog | grep -v 'NXDOMAIN\|NODATA' | awk '{print $8 "\t" $6}' | awk '/CNAME/ {name=$2; getline ; print $0 " " 'name'}'
```

However this method does not work for the following type of log, where there are multiple CNAMEs

```
Jun 20 15:00:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply en.wikipedia.org is <CNAME>                        
Jun 20 15:00:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is <CNAME>              
Jun 20 15:00:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org is 91.198.174.225
```

The previous command gives the following result

```
<CNAME> wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org      en.wikipedia.org
```

By using the first command mentioned along with the second, wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org is associated with 91.198.174.225, however wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is not associated with wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org. The ideal result should be the following

```
91.198.174.225 wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org      en.wikipedia.org
```

To remedy this problem, I believe the file would need to be read backwards, however would doing this not mess up the getline part of awk, to append to the next line?

Ideally, I would like to combine both types of log into a command which would then output everything, rather than having to run both scripts separately. Can anyone assist in mending the awk command to do this?

Here is a sample of "grep reply /var/dnslog", and the desired hosts file to be output. There are other issues that are secondary at the moment. These are highlighted in the desired hosts output.

```
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply photos-a.ak.facebook.com.edgesuite.net is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.25
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.48
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.64
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.9
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.26
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.51
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.8
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.50
Jun 20 15:28:21 dnsmasq[2551]: reply a995.dspmm1.akamai.net is 213.200.108.65
Jun 20 15:28:22 dnsmasq[2551]: reply stackoverflow.com is 64.34.119.12
Jun 20 15:29:41 dnsmasq[2551]: reply www.wikipedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:41 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:41 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org is 91.198.174.225
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply en.wikipedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org is 91.198.174.225
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply ja.wikipedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is <CNAME>
Jun 20 15:29:42 dnsmasq[2551]: reply wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org is 91.198.174.225
```

hosts file

```
213.200.108.26  a995.dspmm1.akamai.net photos-a.ak.facebook.com.edgesuite.net photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net 
##ideally select 1 host at random from multiple of a995.dspmm1.akamai.net, although list may be randomised already so 1st will suffice##
64.34.119.12    stackoverflow.com
91.198.174.225  wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org www.wikipedia.org
91.198.174.225  wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org en.wikipedia.org
91.198.174.225  wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org ja.wikipedia.org 
##Ideally, detect these similarities for wikipedia and convert the 3 lines into this;##
91.198.174.225  wikipedia-lb.esams.wikimedia.org wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org www.wikipedia.org en.wikipedia.org ja.wikipedia.org
```

The intention is that the file will be distributable on a low bandwidth, high latency link, so the file should be as small as possible. I am aware that using this file over a long period of time will cause lots of issues, I have configured the file only to be valid for a short period of time. If anyone can help with the issues pointed out, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, I have a limited range of UNIX applications available. If the above can be achieved in awk, that would be preferable. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` with `sort`:

```
..|awk '{if($8 ~ /<CNAME>/){load=load" "$6}else{print $8" "load" "$6;load=""}}'
  | sort -u -k2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The device I am using does not have the sort command but I used "| awk ' !x[$2]++'" to fix it. Is this ok in terms of efficiency, etc? Is it possible as well to merge mostly duplicated lines, such as the wikipedia example given in the sample? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call using `awk -f parse.awk dnsmasq.log`.

```
/reply/ { 
    host = $6;
    ip = $8;

    names[length(names)+1] = host;

    if (ip !~ /CNAME/) {
    # assign all names up to now the same IP
    # This will overwrite any previous IP assignment as well
    for (i in names) IPs[names[i]] = ip;
    delete names;
    }
}

END {
    # collate hostnames for a particular IP
    for (host in IPs) hosts[IPs[host]] = hosts[IPs[host]]" "host;
    for (IP in hosts) print IP hosts[IP];
}
```